# How to create a new user in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift-enterprise

I am trying to find out how to create a new user in OpenShift enterprise.

According to the documentation (on https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/core_concepts/projects_and_users.html):

> Regular users are created automatically in the system upon first login...

This sounds illogical. How does a user login if they dont have a username and password?

Can someone please clarify this - I'm sure there must be some command for creating a new user, but it is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue with origin which i know is upstream and thus is likely to have issues with docs, but with a system this large, you'd have thought they would have given details as to how to login in the first place.  If you need to log a bug, check this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift+Online

Answer (score 10):

The OpenShift master-config (`/etc/openshift/master/master-config.yaml`) describes the configuration about authentication. By default the master-config shows something like this for the authentication-part:

```
 identityProviders:
  - challenge: true
    login: true
    name: anypassword
    provider:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider
```

This means that every user with every password can authenticate. By performing `oc get users` as system:admin you'll see all the users.
This configuration is not recommended. You're able to configure [another form of authentication](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/configuring_authentication.html#AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider) (htpasswd, ldap, github, ...).

I'm using htpasswd. So than you have to create a file (with htpasswd) which will contain your username + encrypted password. After that you'll need to edit your `master-config.yaml`. You have to tell it to use `HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider` and link to your file.

You can find those steps [here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/configuring_authentication.html#HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider). Don't forget to restart your OpenShift master after performing those steps: `sudo service openshift-master restart` (origin-master for origin).

After creating users you can assign roles to users
Log in with the default admin (system:admin) and assign [roles](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/manage_authorization_policy.html).

Comment: UPDATE: when you're using the ansible playbook to install your environment, than the htpasswd file will be created during the installation.

Comment: Question: the users you create with htpasswd are simple users, right? How can you create an admin?

Comment: It's a while ago but I think you had to login as system:admin with oc and then you can make a user admin by giving him the cluster role cluster-admin: oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin <user_name>

Answer (score 1):

I am creating a script for simply adding a user if OpenShift using `HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider`

```
wget https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64
mv jq-linux64 jq && chmod 755 jq

FILE=$(cat /etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml | python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; y=yaml.load(sys.stdin.read()); print json.dumps(y,indent=4, sort_keys=True)' | ./jq '.oauthConfig.identityProviders[0].provider.file')
FILE=$(sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<<"$FILE")

htpasswd $FILE user1
```